# Error while running an installed Windows Service on dedicated Server

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, service, windows-services

Error while running an installed Windows Service on dedicated Server

I installed my windows service on my virtual dedicated server using the exe file of my windows service.

When I try to run my windows service from a virtual dedicated server then I get following error.

```
 Service cannot be started. System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'MyService.MyServSoap' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.
  at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadChannelBehaviors(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, String configurationName)
at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String configurationName)
at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(String configurationName, EndpointAddress address)
at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
at System.ServiceModel.EndpointTrait`1.CreateSimplexFactory()
at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelFactoryRef(EndpointTrait`1 endpointTrait)
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you invoking an operation on a WCF endpoint from the service? Do you have the *correct* information (address/binding/contract) in your windows service config file?

Comment: @kd7: Yes I do have proper names and address in my windows service config file still it gives the error. I tried all the different possibilities as far as address and endpoint attribute values are concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you supply an app.config for the service .exe?

It looks like it's either missing or incorrect from the exception message:

> Could not find default endpoint
>   element that references contract
>   'MyService.MyServSoap' in the
>   ServiceModel client configuration
>   section. This might be because no
>   configuration file was found for your
>   application, or because no endpoint
>   element matching this contract could
>   be found in the client element.

Comment: I have provided app.config file and also I have created proper endpoint within the app.config file. I tried with various endpoint values but it didnt work.

Comment: @PARTH can you post the endpoint section of the app.config here?