# Error while running a windows service

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, service, windows-services

I have created a windows service and I had installed it on my PC. When I click Start Service from Control Panel. Then I get the following error message.

What could be wrong?

**Error Message in Event Viewer:**

```
 Description:
Service cannot be started. System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at http://www.domain.in/MyServ.asmx that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChann...
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
<Provider Name="Service1" />
<EventID Qualifiers="0">0</EventID>
<Level>2</Level>
<Task>0</Task>
<Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-06-04T05:21:43.000000000Z" />
<EventRecordID>38441</EventRecordID>
<Channel>Application</Channel>
<Computer>TaxSmart30</Computer>
<Security />
</System>
<EventData>
        <Data>Service cannot be started. System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at http://www.mydomain.com/MyServ.asmx that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---&gt; System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
 at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
  at     System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChann...</Data>
 </EventData>
 </Event>
```

Comment: So did you check out the suggestions within the error message? It looks like that URL is incorrect...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Thanks a lot. Yes I changed the URL and this problem got solved. But this windows ervice only works when I install it on my local PC it does not work when I try to install and run it on my virtual dedicated server. What could be wrong?

Comment: Well you say changing the URL fixed one problem, so my guess is you've now got a *different* problem - but we don't know what that is.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I am facing this issue. I had previously posted this question. See the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201631/error-while-running-an-installed-windows-service-on-dedicated-server. What could be wrong?

Comment: I have nothing to add to the answer on the other question. There's no point in talking about that question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the system you are running the service from can see the end point (the asmx address). I've tried the address myself and it works (I hope this is authenticated some how). I would be guessing this may be a firewall issue or connectivity issue for the server running the service (assuming you can confirm this service works from other computers).

Try to ping the dns record to confirm to can reach the endpoint and try to copy and paste the end point address into a browser (from the server having problems) and see if that works.

Comment: No this windows service works fine when installed on my local PC but doesnt work when installed on a virtual dedicated server.

Comment: You can refer to this question to exactly know what error I am getting when I run the same service on my dedicated server. See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201631/error-while-running-an-installed-windows-service-on-dedicated-server. It would be great if you can help.

Comment: @PARTH Because it works fine on your PC my guess would still be connectivity issue, eg, the dedicated server cannot see the endpoint address. If you are able to remote to the server, I would strongly suggest trying to browse to this end point from the server itself.